# linked list function c++ "which is of non-class type 'int'"?

Tags: c++, list

below is the problem in one of the header of a code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "extPersonType.h"
#include "orderedLinkedList.h"

using namespace std;

class addressBookType: public orderedLinkedListType
{
public:
    void print() const;

    void printNameInTheMonth(int month);
    void printInfoOf(string lName);
    void printNamesWithStatus(string status);

    void printNamesBetweenLastNames(string last1,
                                    string last2);

    void insertNode(const extPersonType& eP);

    void searchName(string lName);

    void saveData(ofstream&);

    addressBookType();

private:
    nodeType* searchList(string lName);
};

void addressBookType::print() const
{
    nodeType* current = first;


    while (current != NULL)
    {
        current->info.printInfo();
        cout << endl;
        current= current->link;
    }
}

void addressBookType::printNameInTheMonth(int month)
{
    nodeType* current = first;

    while(current != NULL)
    {
        if (current->info.isMonth(month))
        {
            current->info.print();
            cout << endl;
        }
        current = current->link;
    }
}

void addressBookType::printInfoOf(string lName)
{
    nodeType* location = searchList(lName);

    if (location != NULL)
        location->info.printInfo();
    else
        cout << lName << " is not in address book." << endl;
}

void addressBookType::printNamesWithStatus(string status)
{
    nodeType* current = first;

    while (current != NULL)
    {
        if (current->info.isStatus(status))
        {
            current->info.print();
            cout << endl;
        }
        current = current->link;
    }
}

void addressBookType::printNamesBetweenLastNames(string last1,
                                                 string last2)
{
    string lName;

    nodeType* current = first;

    while(current != NULL)
    {
        lName = current->info.getLastName();

        if (last1 <= lName && lName <= last2)
        {
            current->info.print();
            cout << endl;
        }
        current = current->link;
    }
}

void addressBookType::insertNode(const extPersonType& eP)
{
    orderedLinkedListType::insertNode(eP);
}

void addressBookType::searchName(string lName)
{
    nodeType* location = searchList(lName);

    if (location != NULL)
        cout << lName << " is in the address book" << endl;
    else
        cout << lName << " is not in the address book" << endl;
}


nodeType* addressBookType::searchList(string lName)
{
    nodeType* current = first;
    bool found = false;

    while (current != NULL)
    {
        if (current->info.isLastName(lName))
        {
            found = true;
            break;
        }

        current = current->link;
    }

    return current;
}

void addressBookType::saveData(ofstream& outFile)
{
    string firstN;
    string lastN;

    int month;
    int day;
    int year;

    string street;
    string city;
    string state;
    string zip;

    string phone;
    string pStatus;

    nodeType* current = first;

    while (current != NULL)
    {
        current->info.getDOB(month, day, year);
        current->info.getAddress(street,city,state,zip);
        current->info.getPhoneNumber();
        current->info.getStatus();

        outFile << current->info.getFirstName() << " " 
<< current->info.getLastName() << endl;
    outFile << month << " " << day << " " << year << endl;
    outFile << street << endl << city << endl << state << endl << zip 
<< endl;
    outFile << current->info.getPhoneNumber() << endl
            << current->info.getStatus() << endl;

    current = current->link;
}
}


addressBookType::addressBookType()
{
}
```

these are the two headers file that i suspect that has a problem with it but they have NO ERRORS at all

```
#include <iostream>

#include "linkedList.h"

using namespace std;


class orderedLinkedListType: public linkedListType
{
public:
bool search(const int& searchItem) const;
    //Function to determine whether searchItem is in the list
    //Postcondition: Returns true if searchItem is in the list;
    //               otherwise, the value false is returned.
void insertNode(const int& newItem);
    //Function to insert newItem in the list
    //Postcondition: first points to the new list and
    //        newItem is inserted at the proper place in the list
void deleteNode(const int& deleteItem);
    //Function to delete deleteItem from the list
    //Postcondition: If found, then the node containing the
    //                 deleteItem is deleted from the list;
    //                 first points to the first node of
    //                 the new list
    //               If deleteItem is not in the list,
    //                  an appropriate message is printed
void printListReverse() const;
    //This function prints the list in reverse order
    //Because the original list is in ascending order, the
    //elements will be printed in descending order

private:
void reversePrint(nodeType *current) const;
    //This function is called by the public member
    //function to print the list in reverse order
    };



bool orderedLinkedListType::search(const int& searchItem) const
{
bool found = false;
nodeType *current; //pointer to traverse the list

current = first;  //start the search at the first node

while (current != NULL && !found)
    if (current->info >= searchItem)
        found = true;
    else
        current = current->link;

if (found)
   found = (current->info == searchItem); //test for equality

return found;
}//end search



void orderedLinkedListType::insertNode(const int& newitem)
{
nodeType *current; //pointer to traverse the list
nodeType *trailCurrent; //pointer just before current
nodeType *newNode;  //pointer to create a node

bool  found;

newNode = new nodeType; //create the node
assert(newNode != NULL);

newNode->info = newitem;   //store newitem in the node
newNode->link = NULL;      //set the link field of the node
                           //to NULL

if (first == NULL)  //Case 1
{
    first = newNode;
    count++;
}
else
{
    current = first;
    found = false;

    while (current != NULL && !found) //search the list
       if (current->info >= newitem)
           found = true;
       else
       {
           trailCurrent = current;
           current = current->link;
       }

    if (current == first)      //Case 2
    {
        newNode->link = first;
        first = newNode;
        count++;
    }
    else                       //Case 3
    {
        trailCurrent->link = newNode;
        newNode->link = current;

        count++;
    }
}//end else
}//end insertNode

    void orderedLinkedListType::deleteNode(const int& deleteItem)
{
nodeType *current; //pointer to traverse the list
nodeType *trailCurrent; //pointer just before current
bool found;

if (first == NULL) //Case 1
    cout << "Cannot delete from an empty list." << endl;
else
{
    current = first;
    found = false;

    while (current != NULL && !found)  //search the list
       if (current->info >= deleteItem)
           found = true;
       else
       {
           trailCurrent = current;
           current = current->link;
       }

    if (current == NULL)   //Case 4
        cout << "The item to be deleted is not in the "
             << "list." << endl;
    else
        if (current->info == deleteItem) //item to be
                               //deleted is in the list
        {
            if (first == current)       //Case 2
            {
                first = first->link;
                delete current;
            }
            else                         //Case 3
            {
                trailCurrent->link = current->link;
                delete current;
            }
            count--;
        }
        else                            //Case 4
            cout << "Item to be deleted is not in the "
                 << "list." << endl;
}
} //end deleteNode


void orderedLinkedListType::reversePrint
                        (nodeType *current) const
{
if (current != NULL)
{
    reversePrint(current->link);        //print the tail
    cout << current->info << " ";       //print the node
}
}


void orderedLinkedListType::printListReverse() const
{
reversePrint(first);
cout << endl;
}
```

this is the second one:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <assert.h>

using namespace std;

//Definition of the node


struct nodeType
{
int info;
nodeType *link;
};


class linkedListType
{
public:
const linkedListType& operator=
                     (const linkedListType&);
  //Overload the assignment operator.
void initializeList();
  //Initialize the list to an empty state.
  //Postcondition: first = NULL, last = NULL, count = 0;
bool isEmptyList() const;
  //Function to determine whether the list is empty.
  //Postcondition: Returns true if the list is empty,
  //               otherwise it returns false.
void print() const;
  //Function to output the data contained in each node.
  //Postcondition: none
int length() const;
  //Function to return the number of nodes in the list.
  //Postcondition: The value of count is returned.
void destroyList();
  //Function to delete all the nodes from the list.
  //Postcondition: first = NULL, last = NULL, count = 0;
int front() const;
  //Function to return the first element of the list.
  //Precondition: The list must exist and must not be
  //              empty.
  //Postcondition: If the list is empty, the program
  //               terminates; otherwise, the first
  //               element of the list is returned.
int back()const;
  //Function to return the last element of the list.
  //Precondition: The list must exist and must not be
  //              empty.
  //Postcondition: If the list is empty, the program
  //               terminates; otherwise, the last
  //               element of the list is returned.

bool search(const int& searchItem) const;
  //Function to determine whether searchItem is in the list.
  //Postcondition: Returns true if searchItem is in the
  //               list, otherwise the value false is
  //               returned.

void insertFirst(const int& newItem);
  //Function to insert newItem at the beginning of the list.
  //Postcondition: first points to the new list, newItem is
  //               inserted at the beginning of the list,
  //               last points to the last node in the list,
  //               and count is incremented by 1.

void insertLast(const int& newItem);
  //Function to insert newItem at the end of the list.
  //Postcondition: first points to the new list, newItem
  //               is inserted at the end of the list,
  //               last points to the last node in the list,
  //               and count is incremented by 1.

void deleteNode(const int& deleteItem);
  //Function to delete deleteItem from the list.
  //Postcondition: If found, the node containing
  //               deleteItem is deleted from the list.
  //               first points to the first node, last
  //               points to the last node of the updated
  //               list, and count is decremented by 1.


linkedListType();
  //default constructor
  //Initializes the list to an empty state.
  //Postcondition: first = NULL, last = NULL, count = 0;

linkedListType(const linkedListType& otherList);
     //copy constructor

~linkedListType();
  //destructor
  //Deletes all the nodes from the list.
  //Postcondition: The list object is destroyed.

protected:
int count;   //variable to store the number of
             //elements in the list
nodeType *first; //pointer to the first node of the list
nodeType *last;  //pointer to the last node of the list

private:
void copyList(const linkedListType& otherList);
  //Function to make a copy of otherList.
  //Postcondition: A copy of otherList is created and
  //               assigned to this list.
};



bool linkedListType::isEmptyList() const
{
return(first == NULL);
}


linkedListType::linkedListType() //default constructor
{
first = NULL;
last = NULL;
count = 0;
}


void linkedListType::destroyList()
{
nodeType *temp;   //pointer to deallocate the memory
                        //occupied by the node
while (first != NULL)   //while there are nodes in the list
{
    temp = first;        //set temp to the current node
    first = first->link; //advance first to the next node
    delete temp;        //deallocate the memory occupied by temp
}
last = NULL; //initialize last to NULL; first has already
             //been set to NULL by the while loop
count = 0;
}


void linkedListType::initializeList()
{
destroyList(); //if the list has any nodes, delete them
}


void linkedListType::print() const
{
nodeType *current; //pointer to traverse the list

current = first;  //set current so that it points to
                  //the first node
while (current != NULL) //while more data to print
{
   cout << current->info << " ";
   current = current->link;
}
}//end print



int linkedListType::length() const
{
return count;
}  //end length


int linkedListType::front() const
{
assert(last != NULL);
return first->info; //return the info of the first node
}//end front


int linkedListType::back() const
{
assert(last != NULL);
return last->info; //return the info of the first node
}//end back



bool linkedListType::search(const int& searchItem) const
{
nodeType *current; //pointer to traverse the list
bool found = false;

current = first; //set current to point to the first
                 //node in the list

while (current != NULL && !found)    //search the list
    if (current->info == searchItem) //searchItem is found
        found = true;
    else
        current = current->link; //make current point to
                                 //the next node
return found;
}//end search


void linkedListType::insertFirst(const int& newItem)
{
   nodeType *newNode; //pointer to create the new node

   newNode = new nodeType; //create the new node

   assert(newNode != NULL);      //if unable to allocate memory,
                             //terminate the program

   newNode->info = newItem;        //store the new item in the node
   newNode->link = first;        //insert newNode before first
   first = newNode;              //make first point to the
                             //actual first node
   count++;                //increment count

   if (last == NULL)   //if the list was empty, newNode is also
                  //the last node in the list
  last = newNode;
    }//end insertFirst


    void linkedListType::insertLast(const int& newItem)
    {
   nodeType *newNode; //pointer to create the new node

   newNode = new nodeType; //create the new node

   assert(newNode != NULL); //if unable to allocate memory,
                //terminate the program

   newNode->info = newItem;      //store the new item in the node
   newNode->link = NULL;         //set the link field of newNode
                       //to NULL

   if (first == NULL)  //if the list is empty, newNode is
                //both the first and last node
   {
  first = newNode;
  last = newNode;
  count++;      //increment count
   }
   else     //the list is not empty, insert newNode after last
   {
    last->link = newNode; //insert newNode after last
    last = newNode;   //make last point to the actual last node
  count++;      //increment count
   }
    }//end insertLast



void linkedListType::deleteNode(const int& deleteItem)
{
nodeType *current; //pointer to traverse the list
nodeType *trailCurrent; //pointer just before current
bool found;

if (first == NULL)    //Case 1; the list is empty.
    cout << "Cannot delete from an empty list."
         << endl;
else
{
    if (first->info == deleteItem) //Case 2
    {
        current = first;
        first = first->link;
        count--;
        if (first == NULL)    //the list has only one node
            last = NULL;
        delete current;
    }
    else //search the list for the node with the given info
    {
        found = false;
        trailCurrent = first;  //set trailCurrent to point
                               //to the first node
        current = first->link; //set current to point to
                               //the second node

        while (current != NULL && !found)
        {
            if (current->info != deleteItem)
            {
                trailCurrent = current;
                current = current-> link;
            }
            else
                found = true;
        }//end while

        if (found) //Case 3; if found, delete the node
        {
            trailCurrent->link = current->link;
            count--;

            if (last == current)   //node to be deleted
                                   //was the last node
                last = trailCurrent; //update the value
                                     //of last
            delete current;  //delete the node from the list
        }
        else
            cout << "The item to be deleted is not in "
                 << "the list." << endl;
    }//end else
}//end else
}//end deleteNode


void linkedListType::copyList
               (const linkedListType& otherList)
{
nodeType *newNode; //pointer to create a node
nodeType *current; //pointer to traverse the list

if (first != NULL) //if the list is nonempty, make it empty
   destroyList();

if (otherList.first == NULL) //otherList is empty
{
    first = NULL;
    last = NULL;
    count = 0;
}
else
{
    current = otherList.first; //current points to the
                               //list to be copied
    count = otherList.count;

        //copy the first node
    first = new nodeType;  //create the node

    assert(first != NULL);

    first->info = current->info; //copy the info
    first->link = NULL;        //set the link field of
                               //the node to NULL
    last = first;              //make last point to the
                               //first node
    current = current->link;     //make current point to
                                 //the next node

       //copy the remaining list
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        newNode = new nodeType;  //create a node

        assert(newNode != NULL);

        newNode->info = current->info; //copy the info
        newNode->link = NULL;       //set the link of
                                    //newNode to NULL
        last->link = newNode;  //attach newNode after last
        last = newNode;        //make last point to
                               //the actual last node
        current = current->link;   //make current point
                                   //to the next node
    }//end while
}//end else
}//end copyList


linkedListType::~linkedListType() //destructor
{
   destroyList();
}//end destructor


linkedListType::linkedListType
                (const linkedListType& otherList)
{
first = NULL;
copyList(otherList);
}//end copy constructor

     //overload the assignment operator

const linkedListType& linkedListType::operator=
                  (const linkedListType& otherList)
{
if (this != &otherList) //avoid self-copy
{
    copyList(otherList);
}//end else

 return *this;
}
```

i got an error saying error: request for member 'printInfo' in 'current->nodeType::info', which is of non-class type 'int'. There are few more headers file linking to this header, which all have template coding. However i managed to remove template coding from all the other headers with no errors at all with the exception of this header. can anyone tell me how to solve it?

Comment: The error says it all - your info in nodeType class is int, not a class.

Comment: How `nodeType::info` and `nodeType` are defined?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: struct nodeType
{
 int info;
 nodeType *link;
};

Comment: Without seeing the rest of the code I suspect `printInfo (current->info);` could be what you need,

Comment: Do you have a question that is not answered by the error message?

Answer (score 2):

You defined `struct nodeType` with member `int info;`. But in `addressBookType::printInfoOf` (and `addressBookType::print`) you have the line `location->info.printInfo();`

Since `info` is an `int`, it has no methods to call, `printInfo` or otherwise, thus the error.

It looks like the problem is a result of another type mismatch in your code. `addressBookType`'s `insertNode` takes a `const extPersonType&` (which I assume is defined elsewhere and implements the methods you're trying to use?), but passes it to `orderedLinkedListType::insertNode`, which takes and stores `const int&`. This normally wouldn't work, but at a guess, `extPersonType` is a type (possibly a C++11 strongly-typed `enum`) that has an implicit conversion to `int`, which might avoid compile errors during assignment, but still effectively strips all the `extPersonType`-specific behaviors on `insertNode`, it goes from `extPersonType` to just an `int`.

If you want a general purpose linked list, you need to template it to work with more than just `int`, e.g. changing `nodeType` to:

```
template<typename T>
struct nodeType {
    T info;
    nodeType<T> *link;
};
```

and updating all the methods associated with `nodeType` and the `orderedLinkedListType` to template as appropriate to the specific type, rather than `int`. If you're being lazy, you could instead just change all uses of `int` in `nodeType` and `orderedLinkedListType` to `extPersonType`, but now the code is no good for `int`s, so pick your poison.

Comment: So the member of struct nodetype should be changed? Is there any workaround if I want to retain info as int?

Comment: @LingShiWu: I think you need to figure out what `printInfo` is supposed to do, and what the linked list nodes are supposed to store. I don't see any definition of `printInfo`, and it looks like your `addressBookType` is assuming the linked list stores `extPersonType` as the `info`, not `int`. Usually, a linked list is defined in a templated way, so the data stored in each node is not fixed by the header, e.g. `template<typename T> struct nodeType
{
T info;
nodeType<T> *link;
};` or the like, so you could store `int` or `extPersonType` as appropriate.